# Utilizar el valor de una variable para hacer uso de un objeto con el mismo nombre en JAVA

Tags: java, string, variables

Después de buscar bastante por google no encuentro solución a lo que me planteo.

Necesito, si es que se puede y como ya digo en el título de la pregunta, utilizar el valor de una variable para hacer uso de un objeto con el mismo nombre en JAVA.

Como ejemplo:
Tengo una variable con el valor "labelNombre" y necesito cambiar ciertos atributos de mi JLabel que tiene el mismo nombre labelNombre del modo:

```
labelNombre.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
labelNombre.setEnabled(true); ....
```

los distintos valores de la variable pueden ser "labelDireccion", "labelDNI", "labelTelefono", etc...

GRACIAS, UN SALUDO!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede hacer (de un modo sencillo) lo que pretendes, requeriría del uso del API de reflexión de Java y es algo que no recomendaría usar.

Lo que sí que puedes es agrupar las los objetos en un mapa:

```
Map<String,JLabel> labels = new HashMap<>();
...
labels.put("labelDireccion", new JLabel("Dirección"));
labels.put("labelDNI", new JLabel("DNI"));
...
```

Y de ese modo podrías acceder a la que necesites de un modo sencillo:

```
labels.get("labelDNI").setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
```

Comment: con el Map me va de lujo... muchas gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Conozco dos soluciones posibles. Una de ellas es usar el método estático Class.forName(). Personalmente nunca la he utilizado aunque he oido hablar bastante de ella. Un ejemplo sencillo sacado de https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-reflection-class-forname.html es el siguiente:

**Clase Test**

```
package com.logicbig.example;

public class TestClass {
    private static int a = getAValue();

    private static int getAValue() {
        System.out.println("initializing");
        return 5;
    }
}
```

**Clase Main**

```
package com.logicbig.example;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.logicbig.example.TestClass");
        System.out.println(aClass);
    }
}
```

Otra solución menos elegante sería crear una Clase Factoria que tenga un método instanciate que reciba un string y con un switch escoja la clase adecuada. Esta solución no es mantenible y poco recomendada utilizar (pero si lo necesitas para algo urgente, tambien te puede servir).

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer por reflexión pero solo si labelNombre es un atributo de esa clase, no puede ser una variable local.

Te pego un ejemplo en el que obtengo el valor de un campo a partir de su nombre.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Prueba {

    private Integer micampo = 2;

    public void init() throws Exception {
        Field[] fields = Prueba.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field: fields) {
            if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("micampo")) {
                Object valor = field.get(this);
                System.out.println(valor.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Prueba().init();
    }

}
```

Primero se obtiene el array de campos de la clase (importante aquí no liarse con clases y objetos).

Después por cada campo, busco el que se llama como el que quiero ("micampo").
Cuando lo encuentro, puedo obtener el valor de el objeto (no liarse aquí nuevamente) que yo quiero. En mi caso he puesto this, pero podría ser cualquier objeto de la clase que hayamos obtenido los campos.